# How to use the galera-3 package correctly in Ubuntu 18 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, mysql

`apt-get install galera-3 mysql-server` is successful and creates `/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so`, but `show status like 'wsrep%'` returns nothing.

When I put `wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so` into my mysql configuration, `service start mysql` fails with `unknown variable 'wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so'`.

When I used Galera several years before in Ubuntu 14 LTS, I had to install a galera enabled mysql binary from an external source, but with the availability of the galera-3 package in the Ubuntu 18 repositories I expected that to have changed. Am I wrong ? Or how can I use the `galera-3` package correctly ?

Edit: In Ubuntu 14, there was a package `percona-xtradb-cluster-galera-2.x`, but Ubuntu 18 misses such a package.
 `apt-cache search percona-xtradb-cluster-galera` returns `galera-3` and `percona-galera-3` because they do both break `percona-xtradb-cluster-galera-3.x` accordng to the package descriptions, but there is no such package in the Ubuntu 18 repositories.

https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ  does not mention Galera.